# BATCH FOR-loop but start with specific file

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, cmd, windows-10, nested-for-loop

I have a number of folders in Windows 10, each of which contains a number of PDF files. For each folder I need to run GhostScript with the folder's PDF files as input but with a certain file as the first one.

Each folder contains a file named, say, `"FirstFile-X.pdf"`, where X can be anything, and for each folder I need that file to be the first input.

I have the following in a batch file:

```batch
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set gs="C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.54.0\bin\gswin64.exe"
set options=-dNOPAUSE -q -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite
%gs% -sDEFAULTPAPERSIZE=a4 -dBATCH
for /d %%d in (*) do (
    set a=
    set output=%%d.pdf
    for %%f in (%%d\*.pdf) do (
        set "a=!a!%%d^\%%~nxf "
    )
    %gs% %options% -sOutputFile=!output! !a!
)
```

The above code works but it doesn't take that specific file as the first input. Is it possible to have the innermost `for-loop` run through each file in the order that I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an extra `for` loop that just iterates over the first file matching the pattern `FirstFile-*.pdf` (where only one match is expected). This file could be excluded in the other already present `for` loop. See the explanatory `rem` comments in the code:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
rem // Use quoted `set` syntax to assign unquoted values but still protect special characters:
set "gs=C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.54.0\bin\gswin64.exe"
set "options=-dNOPAUSE -q -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite"
rem // Use quotation during expansion of variables:
"%gs%" -sDEFAULTPAPERSIZE=a4 -dBATCH

for /D %%d in (*) do (
    set "a="
    rem // Let an extra loop find the first file:
    for %%e in ("%%d\FirstFile-*.pdf") do (
        rem /* This condition is just necessary in case more than one files are found
        rem    by the extra loop in order to avoid duplicates in the returned list: */
        if not defined a (
            rem // Append the first file:
            set "a=!a!%%~e "
            rem // Iterate over all files (including first file):
            for %%f in ("%%d\*.pdf") do (
                rem // Exclude already processed first file at this point:
                if /I not "%%~NXf"=="%%~NXe" set "a=!a!%%~f "
            )
        )
    )
    rem // There is no variable `output` needed:
    "%gs%" %options% -sOutputFile=%%d !a!
)
endlocal
exit /B
```

Moreover, I made some other minor improvements, which are also commented in the code.

---

Note, that this code will still have troubles with directory and PDF file paths containing spaces and with such containing the characters `!` and `^`. To overcome them, you will need further quotation and toggling of delayed expansion:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
rem // Use quoted `set` syntax to assign unquoted values but still protect special characters:
set "gs=C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.54.0\bin\gswin64.exe"
set "options=-dNOPAUSE -q -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite"
rem // Use quotation during expansion of variables:
"%gs%" -sDEFAULTPAPERSIZE=a4 -dBATCH

for /D %%d in (*) do (
    set "a="
    set "output=%%d"
    rem // Let an extra loop find the first file:
    for %%e in ("%%d\FirstFile-*.pdf") do (
        rem // Store currently iterated item:
        set "item=%%~e"
        rem /* This condition is just necessary in case more than one files are found
        rem    by the extra loop in order to avoid duplicates in the returned list: */
        if not defined a (
            rem // Toggle delayed expansion to avoid issues with `!` and `^`:
            setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            rem // Append the first file in a quoted manner:
            set "a=!a!"!item!" "
            rem // Transfer value `a` over `endlocal` barrier:
            for /F "delims=" %%t in ("a=!a!") do endlocal & set "%%t"
            rem // Iterate over all files (including first file):
            for %%f in ("%%d\*.pdf") do (
                rem // Store currently iterated item:
                set "item=%%~f"
                rem // Exclude already processed first file at this point:
                if /I not "%%~NXf"=="%%~NXe" (
                    rem // Toggle delayed expansion to avoid issues with `!` and `^`:
                    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
                    rem // Append the current item in a quoted manner:
                    set "a=!a!"!item!" "
                    rem // Transfer value `a` over `endlocal` barrier:
                    for /F "delims=" %%t in ("a=!a!") do endlocal & set "%%t"
                )
            )
        )
    )
    rem // Eventually use delayed expansion as well as quotation:
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    "!gs!" !options! -sOutputFile="!output!" !a!
    endlocal
)
endlocal
exit /B
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your answer inspired me to come up with a different solution that doesn't require an extra nested for-loop. I'll update the post with the new code.

Comment: As of now none of the folders or filenames contain spaces, but I will save this code for when they do :)

Comment: @smlange, I rolled back your question edit to remove your solution. Please post your code as an answer instead, because that is what the answer section is for! Thank you! *N. B.:* You should change the `if` condition in your code to `if /I "!string:~0,5!"=="First"` in order to become case-insensitive…

Comment: Thank you for the tip regarding `if`! I also posted my update as an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

The answer given by @aschipfl inspired me to do a different solution:

```batch
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "gs=C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.54.0\bin\gswin64.exe"
set "options=-dNOPAUSE -q -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite"
"%gs%" -sDEFAULTPAPERSIZE=a4 -dBATCH
for /d %%d in (*) do (
    set a=
    for %%f in (%%d\*.pdf) do (
        set string=%%~nf
        if "!string:~0,5!"=="First" (
            set "a=%%f !a!"
        ) else (
            set "a=!a!%%f "
        )
    )
    "%gs%" %options% -sOutputFile=%%d.pdf !a!
)
endlocal
```

I simply add the filename to the beginning of the string `a`, if the filename starts with "First", and if not the filename is added to the end of the string `a`. I also implemented some of the other small changes that @aschipfl suggested.